# msal Integrated windows auth + conditional access policy for device authentication

Tags: c#, azure-ad-msal

We have a .Net 4.6 framework application, where we try to use Microsoft.Identity.Client library (version 4.22.0.0) to authenticate users.

When we try to acquire a token with Integrated windows auth, we receive an exception
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException: 'AADSTS50097: Device authentication is required.

When we catch this exception and try to acquire a token interactive, this succeeds and we get the token.
Here is the code (scopes omitted for brevity, but are the same in both cases).

We do have a conditional access policy setup in AD, we require that the users are on authenticated devices.

When we check the AD logs, we see that the device information is not sent with the first call, the integrated Windows auth call, therefore AD refuses the authentication, because it cannot verify the device.

For the second call, the interactive call, the device information is send, so AD can approve this one.

Is this a known limitation of the library, or is there a way to make the integrated windows auth call work in this setup?

```
            string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + applicationConfig.TenantID + "/v2.0";
            Application.PublicClient = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(applicationConfig.ClientID)
                .WithAuthority(authority)
                .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
                .Build();

            try
            {
                Application.AuthenticationResult = await Application.PublicClient.AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
            {
                Application.AuthenticationResult = await Application.PublicClient.AcquireTokenInteractive(apiScope).WithExtraScopesToConsent(clientScopes).ExecuteAsync();
            }
```